# Haskell Linear + AD, implementing Metric for Forward?

Tags: haskell, types, automatic-differentiation, haskell-linear

I'm trying to use `diff` from the `ad` package on a function `Quaternion a -> Quaternion a` or more generally `Metric a => a -> a` relying on `quadrance`.

I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is, since `Forward` doesn't have a Metric instance and with `Metric`'s kind as `* -> *` I'm not even sure it's possible (i.e. enforcing that a subtype of Forward has a Metric instance).

I was wondering how I might solve this problem, I'm not married to the idea of a Metric instance, just wanting to get the `diff` of an arbitrary function on Quaternions.

Comment: Can't you just use `abs`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout ```abs``` the function? On a Vector, in place of the squared dot product?

Comment: Can't do `abs` on a vector (well, `linear` does allow this as _element-wise_, but that is nonsense mathematically speaking), but  you can do `abs` on a quaternion.

Comment: @leftaroundabout oh, lol didn't know that! Thanks!